# algoritmo que calcula posibles reuniones entre 2 listas de horarios

Tags: c#

intente varios metodos y cambios pero no logro hacer que el codigo funcione, me entrega un solo horario posible en la lista cuando hay varios. el codigo consiste en un loop que itera en 2 listas mediante el indice y cuando se cumplen ciertas condiciones guarda el horario como una reunion posible. al final la salida es solo un horario posible "10:30 - 11:00" y no veo la razon.
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
string[] times1, times2;
        times1 = new string[] { "10:00 , 11:00", "12:00 , 13:00", "16:00 , 18:00" };
        times2 = new string[] { "08:30 , 09:30", "10:30 , 12:30", "15:00 , 17:00" };

        //24h time to military time, separate strings
        int len = times1.Length * 2;
        string[] times1split, times2split;
        times1split = new string[len];
        times2split = new string[len];
        times1split = times1.SelectMany(s => s.Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "").Split(",")).ToArray();
        times2split = times2.SelectMany(s => s.Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "").Split(",")).ToArray();


        int i = 0;
        int o = 0;
        List<string> horarios = new List<string>();

        while (i < times1split.Length - 1)
        {
            int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(times1split[i]);
            int temp2 = Convert.ToInt32(times2split[o]);
            Console.WriteLine(temp1);
            Console.WriteLine(temp2);

            if (temp1 > temp2)
            {
                if (i % 2 != 0 && o == i + 1 && temp1 - temp2 > 30)
                {
                    horarios.Add(new string(temp2 + " - " + temp1).Insert(2, ":").Insert(10, ":"));
                    o++;
                }

                else
                {
                    o++;
                }
            }

            else if (temp1 < temp2)
            {
                if (o % 2 == 0 && o == i - 1 && temp2 - temp1 > 30)
                {
                    horarios.Add(new string(temp1 + " - " + temp2).Insert(2, ":").Insert(10, ":"));
                    i++;
                }

                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                i++;
                o++;
            }
        }

        foreach (string horario in horarios)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(horario);
        } 

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, si pudieras poner un ejemplo de que es lo que quieres seria de gran utilidad para entender mejor lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Que es lo que plantea tu ejercicio que tienes que hacer

Comment: Un ejemplo sería el siguiente: dos personas tienen distintos horarios, el primero está ocupado de 9 a 10, el segundo de 11 a 12. El algoritmo tomara estos datos en forma de array y deberá calcular cuándo es posible que estás 2 personas tengan una reunión. En este caso el horario posible sería de 10 a 11.

Comment: Pon el enunciado de tu ejercicio, creo que es lo mejor